# Kong for a single service that has public and private resources

Tags: kong

Once you enable an auth plugin for a service all its resources requires authentication, what if I want to whitelist some resources and expose them publicly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same endpoint for anonymous and authenticated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242617/same-endpoint-for-anonymous-and-authenticated-users)

Answer (score 1):

This is just possible if you (a) use request paths to distinguish your APIs (as opposed to using hosts), and (b) use multiple APIs for your resource.

Typical setup with Kong would be to e.g. have a `/private/` and a `/public/` end point, which would typically have different sets of plugins.

E.g., the `/private` one has a `key-auth` plugin (with `acl` to give access rights to the consumers), whereas the `/public` end point would not have any kind of authorization plugin at all (but could still have rate limiting or other kinds of plugins obviously).

Comment: With that do I have to add a security layer myself inside the service that checks from where the request is coming to protect the the private parts inside the public api?

Comment: No, or, well, yes, you have to make sure it's not possible to call the API endpoint directly, without Kong. But other than that: If you secure the `/private` end point using some means, like `key-auth` or similar, you can be sure that it's not possible to call in without a key (i.e. a valid consumer). The `/public` part you would leave without authentication, i.e. freely available.