# Same endpoint for anonymous and authenticated users

Tags: kong

I want to add this endpoint `/graphql` in kong for both anonymous and authenticated users :

- if the apikey is provided consider it as authenticated
- othwerwise consider it as anonymous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `config.anonymous` field in the key-auth plugin I think  by:

1. creating a consumer that you can call ‘anoynmous’ with and id 0 for example
2. use  the kong id of that consumer in anonymous field
3. update your custom code (KongAuthentication) and check if HTTP_X_CONSUMER_CUSTOM_ID = 0 then return AnonymousUser (django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser)